# Can full information about an Oracle schema data-model be selected atomically?

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm instantiating a client-side representation of an Oracle Schema data-model in custom Table/Column/Constraint/Index data structures, in C/C++ using OCI. For this, I'm selecting from:

- all_tables
- all_tab_comments
- all_col_comments
- all_cons_columns
- all_constraints
- etc...

And then I'm using OCI to describe all tables, for precise information about column types. This is working, but our CI testing farm is often failing inside this schema data-model introspection code, because another test is running in parallel and creating/deleting tables in the middle of this serie of queries and *describe* calls I'm making.

My question is thus how can I introspect this schema **atomically** such that another session does not concurrently change that very schema I'm instropecting?

Would using a Read-only Serializable transaction around the selects and describes be enough? I.e. does MVCC apply to Oracle's data dictionaries? What would be the likelihood of *SnapShot too Old* errors on such system dictionaries?

If full atomicity is not possible, are there steps I could take to minimize the possibility of getting inconsistent / stale info?

I was thinking maybe left-joins to reduce the number of queries, and/or replacing the OCIDescribeAny() calls with other dictionary accesses joined to other tables, to get all table/column info in a single query each?

I'd appreciate some expert input on this concurrency issue. Thanks, --DD

Answer (score 1):

a typical read-write conflict. from the top of my head i see 2 ways around it:

1. use [dbms_lock](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm) package in both "introspection" and "another test".
2. rewrite your retrospection query so that it returns one big thing of what you need. there are multiple ways to do that:

   1. use [xmlagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) and alike.
   2. use listagg and get one big string or clob.
   3. just use a bunch of unions to get one resultset, as it's guaranteed to be consistent.

hope that helps.